# Every client shares the same state

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I created a small Blazor Server application that I just test deployed to the cloud.
When I connect to the app from my phone and my laptop, they both always share the same state of the side.

For instance, when I log in on one device, my other device is also logged in.

That is unacceptable behavior; I may have understood the concept wrong.

How to go about this. I need every client to have their own session with the website.

What are my best steps?

Migrate to blazor webassembly? Is this even possible?

Do I have to start over completely?

Go back to ASP.net MVC to keep most of the code?

For instance, I created a singleton just to keep track over if the user is logged in or not:

```
public class Singleton_IsLoggedIn
{
    private static Singleton_IsLoggedIn instance;
    private bool isLoggedIn;

    // Private constructor to prevent external instantiation
    private Singleton_IsLoggedIn()
    {
        isLoggedIn = false; // Default value
    }

    // Property to access the single instance
    public static Singleton_IsLoggedIn Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton_IsLoggedIn();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    // Property to get or set the value
    public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get { return isLoggedIn; }
        set { this.isLoggedIn = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, once I set it to true, it is true for all clients.

Is the issue just the singleton as it is static and I will just need to find another way how to keep track over if a user is logged in or not,
or do literally *all* variables, even the non static ones (which are most of them) share the same state?

Comment: Do not make your state `static`.

Comment: please elaborate on this further. I am in urgent need of help.

Comment: Both `static` and Singleton (DI) literally mean 'shared by all users'. Use a Scoped service and Inject it. Even better, research "Blazor state management".

Answer (score 0):

> That is unacceptable behavior; I may have understood the concept wrong.

> How to go about this. I need every client to have their own session with the website.

> What are my best steps?

You're  complaining - **That is unacceptable behaviour** - about a key application development topic that you clearly don't understand.   Your next best step is to  learn about the differences between Singleton, Scoped and Transient services.  There are plenty of tutorials and articles on the subject. Here are two:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0
- https://chrissainty.com/service-lifetimes-in-blazor/

> For instance, I created a singleton just to keep track over if the user is logged in or not

> Now, once I set it to true, it is true for all clients.

Singleton should be a clue here.  There's one per application, not per user session.